# spark yarn cluster mode (WordCount example)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have a multi-node configuration with Hadoop and Spark. I have confirmed that a worker node has been created with http: // my ip: 8080 /, http: // my ip: 50070. Then, I ran the command "spark-submit --class com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic --master yarn-cluster ~ / Wordcount.jar 10" on the master node. However, "INFO Client: Application report for application_1522727995839_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)" continues to appear. What is the reason ??

INFO Client is

```
 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: N/A
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1522728042534
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://Myip:8088/proxy/application_1522727995839_0001/
         user: My_user
```

My yarn-site.xml.

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8032</value>
</property>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>1536</value>
</property>



</configuration>
```

Comment: It means you've requested too many resources for the operation or your network addresses are misconfigured

Comment: Please take a look at your YARN UI to see how many applications are running and what is the resource utilization.